# Windows 10 - Background Agents/Services?

Tags: service, bluetooth, win-universal-app, windows-10, background-agents

I'm writing a Windows 10 Universal Application, and got to the point where I would like to implement a background service (the application connects to a variety of Bluetooth LE devices, and the Notify characteristics would need to, obviously, notify the device).

But I can't find the BackgroundAgent project definition for Windows 10 apps. Is it deprecated? What must be used instead of that?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a specific **Background Agent** project type (used in Silverlight projects), you need to make a **Windows Runtime Component** and implement `IBackgroundTask` -- see the [Quickstart on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977055.aspx)